# Issue with Al.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, resources

I am creating silverlight solution using VS2010 targeting framework 4.0. I have not provided any SupportedCulture in the csproj file. The satellite assemblies I am creating using al.exe from Microsoft SDKs. The issue is that the culture neutral module is of target framework 4.0.0.0 while the satellite assemblies genetared using al.exe are having target framework 2.0.5.7.
Hence only the culture neutral contents are shown even when the culture setting is changed.

Is there any way to generate satellite assemblies targeting framework 4.0?

Comment: +1 I have the same problem. My projects target the 3.0 framework but my satellite assemblies with specific culture resources get compiled to the 4.0 framework.